# If 1 or both columns has word, then enter text

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula that states: If either or both columns R & S on sheet 'Jan' have "fail" than enter a Y in column K of sheet 'Feb'.
there are 4 possible outcomes:

```
- Fail, Fail
- Fail, Blank
- Blank, Fail
- Blank, Blank
```

I have tried several formulas, but I cannot get it to recognize all 4 scenarios.

`=IF(INDEX(Jan!R:R&Jan!S:S,MATCH(A3,Jan!A:A,0),1)="fail","Y","")` was the closest I've gotten, but it did not insert a "Y" if both cells had "fail"

What am I missing? :(

Comment: Is this more of what you want? This would go in Column K - `=IF(OR(COUNTIF(Jan!R:R,"fail")>0,COUNTIF(Jan!S:S,"fail")>0),"Y","")`?

Comment: It also has to find the code name from column A. Which is why I used the INDEX MATCH. Sorry I forgot to mention that part..  Here is a link to the test workbook. *hopefully the link works*     https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V_fo_FgEhE_xxZlYLOwQgPiEBjoKGxk1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Instead of a link to the workbook, can you post some sample data here, and sample expected output? (I, and I'm sure others, are leery of downloading/opening misc. docs online, especially if macros could be involved).  Thanks!

Comment: Please explain further "It also has to find the code name from column A", be specific.

Comment: New to this, sorry.  what data is needed?   here is an image of what I would like to populate in each scenario:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I0_g6W25lKiYDposu54QZWkaSVV4ZzLC/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, perhaps the following:

```
 =IF(OR(COUNTIFS(Jan!A:A,A3,Jan!R:R,"fail")>0,COUNTIFS(Jan!A:A,A3,Jan!S:S,"fail")>0),"Y","")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Index Match Version

```
=IF(AND(INDEX(Jan!$R:$R,MATCH($A3,Jan!$A:$A,0))<>"fail",INDEX(Jan!$S:$S,MATCH($A3,Jan!$A:$A,0))<>"fail"),"","Y")
```

---

In this version you are checking if both columns do NOT contain "fail". If they don't then "", and in all other three cases "Y".